# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement argepars

Tags: python-3.x

On Mac High Sierra, I encounter the following issue. Please let me know how to resolve. Thanks.

```
$ pip3.7 install argeparse
Collecting argeparse
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement argeparse (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for argeparse
```

Comment: are you sure it's **argeparse**? or it is **argparse**

Comment: also `argparse` should be installed by default with python, shouldn't need pip to install it

Comment: Yes, it should be 'pip3.7 install argparse', not 'pip3.7 install argeparse'. Thanks.